# The float property is not working in my css

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is the code of my html in this when I set the #login id to float right it just overlap the #about-blog id.

```
 #login{
            background-color: #00FFFF;
            float: right;
            width: 70%;
            height: 40%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
         }

   #about-blog{
            background-color: #A4DDED;
            width: 30%;
            height: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
         }
```

Here is the full code {below the code I have provided more information}

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Kvians-Home</title>
 <style type="text/css">
         body {
          background-color: #F0FFF0;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          font-family: monospace;
          font-style: italic;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 20px;
         }
         .main-heading {
          background-color: #0048ba;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 35px;
          font-weight: bold;
          margin: 0px;
         }
         #login{
          background-color: #00FFFF;
          float: right;
          width: 70%;
          height: 40%;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 2;
         }
         #about-blog{
          background-color: #A4DDED;
          width: 30%;
          height: 50%;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
         }
         /* all about links */
         a{
          background-color: #00FF00;
          color: #00693E;
          font-weight: Bold;
          font-size: 25px;
         }
         a:visited{
            background-color: #DFFF00;
            color: #FF7F00;
        }
        a:hover{
         background-color: #91A3B0;
         color: rgb(0,0,0);
        }
        .left-margin{
         margin-left: 5px;
        }
        /* all about links*/
        </style>
</head>
<body> 
<!--facebook SDK-->

<!-- Facebook SDK end-->
  <!--page begin-->
     <h1 class="main-heading">Here You Will Get</h1>
   <!--Main Body Design-->
     <div id="about-blog">
        <h2 class="left-margin">School Feeds</h2>
        <p class="about-blog-para-one left-margin"> Visit our awesome blog,<br> here you will get updates about school</p>
        <a class="left-margin school-feeds"href="http://kvians.weebly.com/school-feeds" target="_blank">Visit</a>
     </div>

    <div id="login">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Login to <strong>Kvians</strong> from your facebook account, just click the login button here</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

how can I set the login to right And just overlap the about blog by a few pixles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using `position:absolute` try  `right:0` instead of `float:right`  and `left:0` instead of `float:left`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `position:absolute` you can't use floating cos the element is detached of the document that's why floating property won't work.

You can use  `right:0` or `left:0` and the element will be forced to go left or right of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Your float doesn't work because you also use `position: absolute`.

I removed `position: absolute`, as it will just give you problems down the road, and added `float: left` to `#about-blog`, this way, if you want to add any extra info, it will flow properly.

```
#login{
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#about-blog{
  background-color: #A4DDED;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;          /*  added  */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.main-heading {
  background-color: #0048ba;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
}
#login{
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#about-blog{
  background-color: #A4DDED;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* all about links */
a{
  background-color: #00FF00;
  color: #00693E;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
a:visited{
  background-color: #DFFF00;
  color: #FF7F00;
}
a:hover{
  background-color: #91A3B0;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.left-margin{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
/* all about links*/
```

```html
<!--facebook SDK-->

<!-- Facebook SDK end-->
  <!--page begin-->
     <h1 class="main-heading">Here You Will Get</h1>
   <!--Main Body Design-->
     <div id="about-blog">
        <h2 class="left-margin">School Feeds</h2>
        <p class="about-blog-para-one left-margin"> Visit our awesome blog,<br> here you will get updates about school</p>
        <a class="left-margin school-feeds"href="http://kvians.weebly.com/school-feeds" target="_blank">Visit</a>
     </div>

    <div id="login">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Login to <strong>Kvians</strong> from your facebook account, just click the login button here</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `margin-left: auto;` to that element using id

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
#login{
                background-color: #00FFFF;
                float: right;
                clear: right;
                width: 70%;
                height: 40%;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
             }
```

I added `clear: right;` on it, I think it will work!